# How to get the current web url in __redirect in custom new form?

Tags: 2013, redirect, save, newform

I have created one custom new form of a list in which I want to redirect the user to other page after saving item.

I have placed `<input>` button to save the item and set the `__redirect` attribute to  my custom page in `Pages` library. My site url is like, `<sitecollection>/Pages/Page.aspx` for e.x., `http://xxx/sites/web/Pages/Page.aspx`.

My HTML code in `CustomNewForm.aspx` is:

```
<input type="button"
       value="Save"
       onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirect={/Pages/Test.aspx}')}" />
```

But when press save button it redirects me to `http://xxx/Pages/Test.aspx` rather than `http://<sitecollection/site/web/Pages/Test.aspx`

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

try using the below script on NewForm.aspx

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">function PreSaveAction() {
    var URL = location.pathname.replace('NewForm.aspx', 'DispForm.aspx');
    if (GetUrlKeyValue('IsDlg') === '1') {
        URL += "?IsDlg=1";
    }
    $("#aspnetForm").attr('action', location.pathname + "?Source=" + URL);
    return true;
}</script>
```

Pass the custom URL instead of DispForm.aspx. It should work.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I am trying this way. And will I be able to get the ID of the added item? suppose, what if I want to pass the item id in the action attribute as query string parameter?

Comment: you can refer the link : http://spjsblog.com/2011/04/23/redirect-from-newform-to-dispform-or-editform/

Answer (score 0):

Try using `_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl`

It gives you the absolute url of the web. So it will give `http://<sitecollection/site/web/`

Comment: it is taking _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl as text, i.e. the __redirect includes _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl as a part of url.

Comment: You need to create a variable and then append it. Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17814847/how-to-pass-variable-to-href-in-genfireserverevent-to-redirect-url

Comment: If I declare the variable in inline JavaScript, the thing is not getting updated.